# Successfully parsing this deeply nested JSON list

Tags: python, json, list, nested-lists

I have a JSON object being returned in the following format:

```
[[[13,
   u'Arsenal',
   [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'header', [1]],
      [u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]],
      [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]],
      [u'goal', u'owngoal', u'rightfoot', [1]],
      [u'miss', u'corner', u'header', [2]],
      [u'miss', u'corner', u'leftfoot', [3]],
      [u'miss', u'corner', u'rightfoot', [2]],
      [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot', [2]],
      [u'miss', u'directfreekick', u'leftfoot', [1]],
      [u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [2]],
      [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [16]],
      [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]]]]]]]]
```

When I use this code:

```
for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:
        regex = {tuple(sub[:3]): sub[3][0] for y in events[0] for sub in y}
```

I get the nested list above returned as a dictionary, the keys of which are made up of tuples derived from the above text values, with the values also derived from the above nested lists.

I then have this slightly different data structure (again JSON):

```
[[[13,
   u'Arsenal',
   [[6.125,
     [[u'assist', u'cross', [3]],
      [u'normal', u'cross', [198]],
      [u'normal', u'longball', [326]],
      [u'assist', u'short', [5]],
      [u'normal', u'short', [4726]],
      [u'assist', u'throughball', [1]],
      [u'normal', u'throughball', [35]]]]]]]]
```

As far as I can tell, the only difference between this and the first set of nested lists (apart from there being two rather than three text elements per list) is the value '6.125,' which is contained between a set of the nested brackets. So to my mind the following code should allow me to parse the second data structure:

```
for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:
        regex = {tuple(sub[:2]): sub[2][0] for y in events[0] for sub in y}
```

However this returns the following error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone tell me what I am misunderstanding and the syntax to correct my issue?

Comment: First off, the code in question is not JSON.

Comment: At a guess you are trying to iterate over, or tuple assign the `6.125` value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hi, thanks for replying. do you have a suggestion at all about how I could amend my code?